# mathcal in beamer does not work

Tags: math-mode

I have a symbol in my presentation(beamer) that should be `\mathcal{P}`, but it appears like the following:
[image]
I want this:
[image]

could you help me with that? Thanks

This is the code:

````
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,dsfont}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{mathtools} % must go before semantic
%\usepackage{semantic}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage{ thmtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,dsfont}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}  #I want the font be serif
\usetheme{Madrid}}




\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{\mathcal{P}}_{\mathrm{A}}\!= [\boldsymbol{P}_{\mathrm{m},1}, \boldsymbol{P}_{\mathrm{m},2},  \cdots, \boldsymbol{P}_{\mathrm{m},N} ]^\top
\end{align}
\end{document}```
````

Comment: Can you post `MWE` from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have edited the question.

Comment: Still no `\documentclass` in your MWE.

Comment: the ``` \documentclass{beamer}```is at the top of that. I've just edited again

Comment: Why are you running boldsymbol on everything, that is unlikely to be always weldefined

Comment: They are vectors, I want to show that they are vectors. Then I have used the boldsymbol

Comment: @Meskaj: You're probably compiling this on Overleaf? Remove `\usepackage{flexisym}` and things will compile to the desired output. There are a number of unnecessary packages you're loading (also some twice).

Comment: @Werner Thank you so much. It works:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `flexisym` from your preamble. The following minimal example provides the desired output.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif} %I want the font be serif

\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\[
  \boldsymbol{\mathcal{P}}_{\mathrm{A}} = [
    \boldsymbol{P}_{\mathrm{m},1}, \boldsymbol{P}_{\mathrm{m},2}, \dots, \boldsymbol{P}_{\mathrm{m},N}
  ]^\top
\]

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The culprit is package `flexisym`, which cause error:

```
\mathchardef\ordinarycolon\mathcode`\:
```

and after forcing compilation gives wrong character.

Do you really need this package?  Removing them gives desired result:

[image]

BTW, you need to clean-up your document preamble. In it you load soma packages, twice, also load packages which are already load by `beamer` (as `graphicx`, `amsmath` etc).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}  %I want the font be serif
\usetheme{Madrid}

\mode<presentation> {
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs, dsfont}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{semantic}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{commath}
    }


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\mathcal{P}}_{\mathrm{A}}
    = [\boldsymbol{P}_{\mathrm{m},1}, \boldsymbol{P}_{\mathrm{m},2},  \cdots, \boldsymbol{P}_{\mathrm{m},N} ]^\top
\end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```